# The dataframe read from xlsx file edited by openpyxl is empty

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I've used openpyxl to edit the formulas in my table and save it as a new xlsx file. After doing these, I directly applied pandas to read this new xlsx file, but what I got is an empty dataframe.

Having found this, I open the new xlsx file and click the 'save' button. Then, pandas can read this file as expected.

What I'm wondering now is why this issue happened and how can I avoid the 'save' step.

Comment: If you are using openpyxl don't forget to save and close (or use a context manager). Also pandas read the first sheet, if there is multiple sheet provide the exact name to be sure it read it.